# Can the Location Services tell me where my iPhone was this morning?

Tags: iphone, geolocation

Since my boss requires timesheets, it'd help for me to know exactly what time I got to the office in the morning, since I'm woefully bad at keeping track of this on my own.

I can't seem to find any info on Google (most results involve *good morning* and otherwise led me this community). Was hoping someone here could shed some light on it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If location services are enabled, your iPhone maintains a log of **Significant Locations**. You can find them under Settings app → Privacy → Location Services → System Services → Significant Locations. Check for **History** section. Tapping on History will list the locations recorded by your iPhone.

[image] [image]

You also have the option to view and delete the individually recorded location data.

[image] [image]

If you are concerned about your privacy, you can also choose to clear the location data any time. This data is sensitive and handled very carefully by Apple. It is not shared with 3rd party apps, is encrypted and cannot be read by Apple.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :) Really cool but also kinda scary if you think about it :P Can Apple see this or does the encryption keep it secure even from them?

Comment: @Ortund Kindly read through the answer text carefully. I have already addressed the concerns.